# Video with poster image for mobile view or responsive view

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to play a single video on website.so please suggest me some plugins or a way to do this.Site is in wordpress.Here is the requirement.
1- Single video with poster image so that if responsive view or mobile view or slow connection then the poster image will appear.
2-This should not be a slider.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok...I got this...
I can do this by using simple html5  video tag.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp